# Laravel Authentication using different model rather than the user model

Tags: laravel, authentication, model, eloquent

All about laravel authentication is based on users, but I have deleted the user model and replaced that with a company model, so, basically, I want my users (laravel authentication users) to be companies.

Laravel doesn't like this, it gives me

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\company given, called in /home/dhiraj1site/Desktop/Documents/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.p
```

This error, and if I import authenticable class as suggested in similar questions. Laravel hates this and gives me a blank page.

I have companies model and a companies table, I want the users to sign up as companies, and login as companies. How should I go about this, I am really confused and stuck on this stage, please help me understand how authentication works (I have read authentication documentation several times) and how should I change 'Users' to 'companies'.

Comment: Please post your `code`

Comment: have you extended your `Comany` model via `extends Authenticatable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to skin this cat zuif. The 'Laravel' way would be to edit the settings in `app/config/auth.php`

In that file you'll need to change the line: `'model' => 'App\User'` to `'model' => 'App\Company'`.

The 'gotcha' with Laravel is that you must remember to implement the right interfaces in your new 'user' class, Company:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Company extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Or for newer versions of Laravel, its' just one interface:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Company extends Authenticatable
```

I've done this before and it worked well for me.  You could also get creative with extending the User class, but I think above is what you are hunting for.
HTH

Comment: Thank you. It's giving me Interface 'Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface' not found
error

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure what version of Laravel you had.  I edited to add newer version interface.  Try the above please.

Comment: Hey, I ran into a different problem, so companies can register perfectly, but those companies cannot sign in, the auth::attempt does not recognize the username/password combination, I was wondering if this is somehow related with changing users to companies? Any ideas?